# Update tags of all resources attached to an EC2 instance

Tags: amazon-ec2, aws-cli, tagging

How do you update tags of all resources attached to an EC2 instance using the AWS CLI?

The issue is that we have wrongly tagged resources and we want to update the tags associated with the resources attached to an EC2 instance. For example, attached volumes, ElasticIp, and snapshots should all be updated when we update the tags for an EC2 instance.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`create-tags`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/Using_Tags.html) to tag multiple resources with multiple tags at once, such as:

`aws ec2 create-tags --resources i-1234567890abcdef0 vol-049df61146c4d7901 eipalloc-12345678 snap-1234567890abcdef0 --tags Key=webserver,Value=  Key=stack,Value=Production`

Comment: your suggestion helped me @enharmonic